# How to open a file through python with folder name a regular expression?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I want to open a file ex: xyz.txt which is in a folder named ex: abc_4564536_01_r4897934.
Now let suppose I only know that folder name consist of "4564536_01" and there is no other folder with the same string in its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post title asks for a solution involving regular expressions, but `glob` is probably a better choice.

`glob.glob()` returns a list of filenames that match a certain pattern.

```
import glob

fname = glob.glob("*4564536_01*/xyz.txt")[0]
with open(fname) as fp:
    print fp.read()
```